# how to get the count of the column value of a particular row?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a table below.

[image]

how to get the count of the column value whose value is 'M' in a particular row?

ex:  If i give the condition, where shape_name='Rectangle' it will return the count of the column whose value is = 'M'. Result: count is 2

If True L-Left=> Result: count is 4
How to get the answer.? plz help me to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution with CASE WHEN is like this:

```
SELECT shape_name,
      CASE WHEN a = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN b = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
      CASE WHEN c = 'm' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as mcount
  FROM t1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/25f8c/9)

Just adjust the SQL to your table structure - you will need to find more `CASE WHEN` statements for each column

Answer (score 0):

Very old solution - fetch all columns, iterate through all of them, and count occurrences of `M`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select SHAPE_NAME ,
            DECODE(COLUMN_NAME1,'M',1,0)+
            DECODE(COLUMN_NAME2,'M',1,0)+
            DECODE(COLUMN_NAME3,'M',1,0)+
            DECODE(COLUMN_NAME4,'M',1,0) your_count
 from  YOUR_TABLE where shape_name='Rectangle' ;
```